# An interesting approach to an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I found this integral somewhere, wolfram alpha did spit out an answer but I am trying to solve it by myself.

The integral is
$\int\sqrt{2^x-1}\ln(2^x-1)dx$

My approach is noticing that the integrand resembles the derivative of some function $f(n)=(2^x-1)^n$

We can define $I(n)=\int(2^x-1)^ndx$

Thus $I'(n)=\int(2^x-1)^n \ln(2^x-1)$dx

And our integral is $I'(\frac12)$

I wasted enough time on this, and I'm asking if this approach will lead somewhere, or you could maybe guide me through it.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not an elementary integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the give integral as:
\begin{gather*}
\int \sqrt{\left( 2^{x} -1\right)} ln\left( 2^{x} -1\right) dx\\
let\ 2^{x} -1=t\\
2^{x} ln2\ dx=dt\\
dx=\frac{dt}{( t+1) ln2}\\
Substitute\ back:\\
\int t^{\frac{1}{2}} lnt\times \frac{dt}{( t+1) ln2}\\
\\
\end{gather*}
Can you attempt this integral using integration by parts?

Hint: Use ln(t) as the first part and

\begin{gather*}
\frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}{t+1}\\
\\
\end{gather*} as the second part.

Comment: To the downvoter, can you pls provide the reason for the downvote? I'll try to improve my next answer based on the suggestion you provide.